Github Actions Self-Hosted Runner issue with node 20
I am running Github Actions Self Hosted Runner on a Ubuntu VM:
~$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"

I am running Actions Runner version 2.317.0
In the context of the notice by the Github team: Notice
I am using the GitHub Actions:
jobs:
  my-job:
      runs-on: [my-ubuntu]
      timeout-minutes: 120
      container:
        image: my-image-path:latest
        credentials:
          username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}

      steps:
        - name: Checkout Source Code
          uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.7


But when the job executes, I get this Error in the Job logs:
/usr/bin/docker exec  XXXX sh -c "cat /etc/*release | grep ^ID"
/__e/node20/bin/node: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.28' not found (required by /__e/node20/bin/node)

On the Ubuntu VM, I have node installed already, and it is running as expected; not sure why the runner is complaining about not being able to run node 20
# Self-Hosted Runner Ubuntu 20.04
$ node -v
v20.15.0

Additional info:
$ ldd --version
ldd (Ubuntu GLIBC 2.31-0ubuntu9.16) 2.31
Copyright (C) 2020 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.

Currently to circumvent the downtime of CI, I am running the scripts as below:
bash -c 'ACTIONS_ALLOW_USE_UNSECURE_NODE_VERSION=true run.sh' > nohup.out 2>&1 &

## and github actions
      steps:
        - name: Checkout Source Code
          uses: actions/checkout@v3


